# Need help forming jquery selector with find and contains, with two conditions

Tags: jquery, selector

I looked at some other articles here and elsewhere but nothing was exactly what I'm trying to implement.

Please take a look at this xpath query (using mozxpath.js file to clone IE functionality)

```
var XMLObj.selectSingleNode("/Catalog/Albums/Album/Tracks/Track[../../AlbumNo='" + AlbumNo + "' and ./TrackNo = '" + TrackNo + "']");
```

How can I convert this expression to jquery?

I tried the following to get me started and it only selects the AlbumNo node:

```
$(XMLObj).find("AlbumNo:contains(" + AlbumNo + ")", "TrackNo:contains(" + TrackNo + ")");
```

The xpath expression is looking for the Track node where both conditions are met.  How can I rewrite the xpath expression to something jQuery friendly?

Thank you.

**Edit**

Here is the dumbed-down version of the XML structure:

```
<Catalog>
  <Albums>
    <Album>
      <AlbumNo>1</AlbumNo>
      <Tracks>
        <Track>
          <TrackNo>1</TrackNo>
        <Track>
          <TrackNo>2</TrackNo>
        <Track>
          <TrackNo>3</TrackNo>
        <Track>
          <TrackNo>4</TrackNo>
        <Track>
          <TrackNo>5</TrackNo>
        <Track>
          <TrackNo>6</TrackNo>
        <Track>
          <TrackNo>7</TrackNo>
        <Track>
          <TrackNo>8</TrackNo>
        <Track>
          <TrackNo>9</TrackNo>
        <Track>
          <TrackNo>10</TrackNo>
        <Track>
          <TrackNo>11</TrackNo>
        <Track>
          <TrackNo>12</TrackNo>
      </Tracks>
    </Album>
  </Album>
</Catalog>
```

Comment: Poasting your XML structure would be helpful.

Comment: Okay, sure, I'll post a trimmed down version of the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of the XML structure would be helpful.

I don't think you can achieve the same with a single selector, you have to use a more complex structure:

```
$(XMLObj).find('Album').filter(function() { // filter albums by album number
    return !!$(this).find('AlbumNo').filter(function() { 
        return $(this).text() == AlbumNo;
    }).length;
}).find('Track').filter(function() { // filter tracks by track number
    return !!$(this).find('TrackNo').filter(function() { 
        return $(this).text() == TrackNo;
    }).length;
});
```

It would definitely be easier if the numbers were attributes of the elements and not descendants.

The reason why I use another `filter` function instead of `:contains` is that it is the only way you can search for an exact match. `:contains` will also match if the text you search is only a *substring*. That is, if you search for track number `1`, `:contains` would also match track number `10`, `11`, `12`, etc.

---

If you have to do similar things quite often, it might be useful to extend jQuery with a function which filters elements with certain subelements with certain content.

For example:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.whichContains = function(element, content) {
        return this.filter(function() {
            return !!$(this).find(element).filter(function() { 
                return $(this).text() == content;
            }).length;
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

which can be used as

```
$(XMLObj)
  .find('Album').whichContains('AlbumNo', AlbumNo)
  .find('Track').whichContains('TrackNo', TrackNo)
```

Comment: I wish I can one-up you again!  This is freaking brilliant.  It works wonderfully.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

comma deliminators as a means of including other elements requires the comma to be in the quotes:

```
$(XMLObj).find("AlbumNo:contains(" + AlbumNo + "),TrackNo:contains(" + TrackNo + ")");
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  You statement selects multiple nodes, which is actually very useful.  As a note for other readers, it doesn't address my original problem.  But I appreciate your correction and teaching me something new.

Comment: @user717236 oh, terribly sorry about that.  I completely misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

I've setup a jsfiddle that selects the requested `TrackNo` element within the requested `AlbumNo` element: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/tDhLF/.

Here is the selector I used:

```
$(xml_string).find('AlbumNo:contains(' + AlbumNo + ')').next('tracks').find('TrackNo:contains(' + TrackNo + ')');
```

Comment: I'd assume that the actualy XML is more complicated and the elements are not necessarily in the order the OP posted.

Comment: Jasper, thank you very much! This is also a great solution albeit it selects the TrackNo node, not the appropriate Track node. I modified your solution to: $(xml_string).find('AlbumNo:contains(' + AlbumNo + ')').siblings('tracks').find('TrackNo:contains(' + TrackNo + ')').parent();  So, thank you very much for your help.  If it weren't for your help, I wouldn't have been able to ultimately realize the solution. Felix Kling is correct, in that the XML is a bit more complex.  Thanks again.